# Express: command not found

Tags: node.js, express, npm

On OSX, I've installed ExpressJS via

```
sudo npm install express-generator -g
```

without errors, but I still get

```
-bash: express: command not found
```

This is what I got when installing:

```
/Users/myusername/.node/bin/express -> /Users/myusername/.node/lib/node_modules/express-generator/bin/express
express-generator@4.9.0 /Users/myusername/.node/lib/node_modules/express-generator
├── commander@1.3.2 (keypress@0.1.0)
└── mkdirp@0.5.0 (minimist@0.0.8)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: How did you install node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add the spot that NPM installs executables to to your `$PATH`.

```
 PATH="$HOME/.node/bin:$PATH"
```

This is a one time setting; to keep this permanent, read [How to add a directory to my path?](https://askubuntu.com/q/60218/301559) on Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the parent folder where node_module exists and use bellow command.

```
    npm install -g express-generator
```